# In Angular 14, using module federation, how do I determine the absolute path of my remote app from within the remote app?

Tags: angular, path, remoteapp, angular-module-federation, module-federationnextjs-mfutils

I'm using Angular 14 and module federation.  How do I find the absolute path of my remote application from within my remote application?  In my remote application, I expose the module using

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'checklogo',

  exposes: {
    './Component': './src/app/app.component.ts',
    './start':'./src/app/my-products/my-products.module.ts'
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

and then in my src/app/services I have this

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

    ...
     public init() {
        const absolutePath = ???
        this.configuration = initFile(`${absolutePath}/config.json`);
```

In my shell application, I reference the remote module when I init my routes like so

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    ...
      {
        path: 'my-products',
        initChildren: () =>
            initRemoteModule({
                type: 'module',
                remoteEntry: getRemoteEntryUrl(),
                exposedModule: './start'
            })
            .then(m => m.MyProductsModule)
      },
```

I don't quite know what to put in the "const absolutePath = ???" line of my "init" method within the service.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, the `remote entries` should be defined in the **shell** app (not in the **remote** one) either in a static way or dynamically.

**Static Federation approach:**

```js
// projects\shell\webpack.config.js

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  remotes: {
    mfe1: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
  },
  //...
}
```

**Dynamic Federation approach:**

Adjust the shell's main.ts (projects/shell/src/main.ts) as follows:

```js
import { loadManifest } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

// You can use a JSON manifest from assets or from server: 
loadManifest('assets/mf.manifest.json')
  .catch((err) => console.error('Error loading remote entries', err))
  .then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

The JSON manifest content should be as follows:

```json
{
  "mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"
}
```

For more details about Webpack Module Federation in Angular, see: https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/tutorial/tutorial.md

Comment: I'm not understanding how I get the absolute URL in the remote application from this answer.  Also, you are hard-coding "http://localhost:4201" in a couple of places.  This might work locally, but this won't work across different environments (qa, production).  The solution needs to be flexible enough to work everywhere.

Comment: As I mentioned in the dynamic federation approach, you can fetch and load the mfe-manifest from the server either by 1) a separate endpoint to return all the remote URLs related to this environment, or by 2) storing them in a JSON config file in the app's assets that would be replaced in the deployment process for each environment (qa, prod... etc).

Comment: I guess I'm still pretty new and this module federation stuff, but could you include the code that woudl be run in the remote application that would determine its absolute path?

Comment: It's not something that you determine in the remote apps. The remote URL refers to the server where you deployed this remote app. Each remote app should be deployed to a separate URL. If you're deploying the remote apps to the same server and the same base URL of your app (but in a subdirectory), then you can use the relative paths in your mfe manifest.

Comment: So you're saying the remote application cannot determine its own URL without knowledge of or interaction with the shell application?  That doesn't seem right but again, I'm a novice at this.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I mean even if you added the app URL in the remote (mfe) environment or config files, it doesn't matter. What matters is where you deployed the MFE app and on which URL you plan to access it from another shell (mfe) app or as a separate app.